# Photoshop Script: combine 3 images side-by-side

Tags: javascript, image, batch-file, photoshop-script

I'm needing to take a folder of about 500 1024x768 resolution images, and combine them three at a time into a solid panorama at 3072x768.  (Not Photoshop's photomerge)

I am by no means a programmer; just stumbled upon this site and everyone seems very helpful.  I'm leaning that using a java script inside Photoshop is probably my best bet.

I'll rename the source files to:

Image_SD_1a

Image_SD_1b

Image_SD_1c

Image_SD_2a

...and so on...

One each three-image is built, it needs to save into another folder as a JPG, as:

Image_001

Image_002

...and so on... But I can do a batch rename after of course.

I searched and found these two scripts that are close, but I'm not smart enough to add a "third" image step, or change the file name structure.

[How to batch combine two unique series of images into a single side-by-side image in Photoshop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368429/how-to-batch-combine-two-unique-series-of-images-into-a-single-side-by-side-imag)

[Merging files together (side by side) in folder Photoshop scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530943/merging-files-together-side-by-side-in-folder-photoshop-scripts)

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: ImageMagick would probably be your best bet.  [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076293/).  I think `convert +append Image_SD_1* Image_001.jpg` would be the appropriate syntax to merge Image_SD_1[abc].jpg into Image_001.jpg.  You could use a `for /L` loop to perform this command many times.

Answer (score 1):

This script will do what you want. 
It works on these principles:

- All your images (Image_SD_1a.jpg, Image_SD_1b.jpg, Image_SD_1b.jpg) are in the same directory.
- The images are jpegs (will be saved out as Image_SD_1abc.jpg)
- The images will be saved out in the same folder as the other images.
- Open image A AND THEN run the script.

It's not perfect, and it could be improved and made better, but tired and I'm running out of coffee. Script is as follows:

```
//pref pixels
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;


// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var ext = getFileExtension(srcDoc);
var docPath = srcDoc.path;

// get original width and height
var imageW = srcDoc.width.value;
var imageH = srcDoc.height.value;

// name the mother
var docName = srcDoc.name;

// get names for images B & C
var imageStub = getImageName(docName);
var imageB = docPath + "/" + imageStub + "b" + ext;
var imageC = docPath + "/" + imageStub + "c" + ext;

// load image B % copy it
openThisFile(imageB);
activeDocument.selection.selectAll();
activeDocument.selection.copy();
activeDocument.selection.deselect();
app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);


// return to image A
app.activeDocument = srcDoc;

// paste it
activeDocument.paste();
translateLayer(imageW, 0);

// do the same for C
// load image C % copy it
openThisFile(imageC);
activeDocument.selection.selectAll();
activeDocument.selection.copy();
activeDocument.selection.deselect();
app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);

// return to image A
app.activeDocument = srcDoc;

// paste it
activeDocument.paste();
translateLayer(imageW *2, 0);


// resize canvas
srcDoc.resizeCanvas(imageW *3, imageH, AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);

// flatten it
srcDoc.flatten();

// save it out
var tempName = imageStub + "abc";
saveMe(docPath, tempName, 12);

// close the new doc
app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);

function getImageName (astring)
{
  // Image_SD_1a.jpg
  astring += "";
  //re move extension -1
  var temp = astring.substring(0, astring.lastIndexOf("."));
  return temp.substring(0, temp.length-1);
}

function getFileExtension (astring)
{
  astring += "";
  var x = astring.substring(astring.lastIndexOf("."), astring.length-1);
  //alert(x);
  return x;
}

// function OPENTHISFILE (masterFileNameAndPath)
// --------------------------------------------------------
function openThisFile(masterFileNameAndPath)
{
  var fileRef = new File(masterFileNameAndPath)
  if (fileRef.exists)
  //open that doc
    {
      app.open(fileRef);
    }
  else
    {
      alert("error opening " + masterFileNameAndPath)
    }
}

function saveMe(fPath, fname, myJpgQuality)
{
  //vegetables 
  if (!myJpgQuality) myJpgQuality = 12;

  // Set filePath and fileName to source path
  filePath = fPath + "/" + fname + ".jpg";

  var jpgFile = new File(filePath);
  jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.OPTIMIZEDBASELINE;
  jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
  jpgSaveOptions.quality = myJpgQuality;

  activeDocument.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}

function translateLayer(dx,dy)
{
  // =======================================================
  var id2014 = charIDToTypeID( "Trnf" );
  var desc416 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id2015 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref287 = new ActionReference();
  var id2016 = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
  var id2017 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
  var id2018 = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
  ref287.putEnumerated( id2016, id2017, id2018 );
  desc416.putReference( id2015, ref287 );
  var id2019 = charIDToTypeID( "FTcs" );
  var id2020 = charIDToTypeID( "QCSt" );
  var id2021 = charIDToTypeID( "Qcsa" );
  desc416.putEnumerated( id2019, id2020, id2021 );
  var id2022 = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
  var desc417 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id2023 = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
  var id2024 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
  desc417.putUnitDouble( id2023, id2024, dx );
  var id2025 = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
  var id2026 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
  desc417.putUnitDouble( id2025, id2026, dy );
  var id2027 = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
  desc416.putObject( id2022, id2027, desc417 );
  executeAction( id2014, desc416, DialogModes.NO );
}
```